# Drupal : Cleanest way to loop throught field_image in a node template

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am theming a node in my new Drupal 7 theme and I want to use a slideshow with custom markup.

My node has a image field (field_image) containing several images.

For now I can retrieve generate the code with this :

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$image = $content['field_image']["#object"]->field_image;
//htmldump($image);

foreach ($image as $key=>$value) {

  $output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_image', $image[$key], array(
    'type' => 'image',
    'settings' => array(
      'image_style' => 'thumbnail', //place your image style here
      'image_link' => 'content',
    ),
  ));
  print render($output);
}
```

And this works OK but I am not sure this is the best way to do this.

1) How I could use "suggestion" or "hook" (I am not very familiar to this concept and have just used those present by default in my template.php)

2) Is `$content['field_image']["#object"]->field_image;` robust and update proof ?

**EDIT :**
`<div class="b-slick">
   <div class="b-slick__slide"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/blabla/pic1.jpg" width="978" height="651" alt=""></div>
  <div class="b-slick__slide"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/blabla/pic2.jpg" width="978" height="651" alt=""></div>
</div>`

Comment: hmmm... there's a few modules that provide slideshows, have you looked into those? if that's not an option then think you need to share a bit more of what the markup being generated by Drupal is missing so we can help..

Comment: Thx Alberto, but as I wrote, the result works pretty well. But it seems so verbose to me. So I wonder if is there is a cleaner way to get the same result.
Plus : `$image = $content['field_image']["#object"]->field_image;
`seems a bit weak to me. I will edit to show you the result markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
<?php 
foreach ($content['field_images'] as $key=>$image):
if(is_numeric($key)): 
print render($content['field_images'][$key]); 
endif;
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Yes! More concise. But I lose the control option array.

Comment: control option array? Please explain

Comment: It is the array in field_view_value() un my question. It allows me to choose the size, set a link, etc.

Comment: You can manage those options by changing display settings of the field under Manage Display of that content type.